# boost::make_shared reference to created shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost

I want to make another thread in my application, so I'm doing it that way:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> wild_thread;

void thread_routine(wild_thread t) {
    // do stuff
}
int main() {
    {
        wild_thread t;
        t.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&thread_routine, t)));
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

But this is ugly, I need to name this temporary shared_ptr.

So, the question is, can I do this with `boost::make_shared` anyhow? Can I somehow ask it to bind newly created shared_ptr into my thread_routine? Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: It also looks unsafe. Are you passing `t` before it is initialized?

Comment: Well, I can do `wild_thread t; t.reset(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&thread_routine, t)))`.

Comment: @IvanTolstosheyev: No, you can't. You are trying to pass pointer to object that was not allocated yet, which is not possible, because the pointer is not known yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass the thread pointer `t` into your `thread_routine` with `boost::bind` because `t` isn't initialized until after the thread has been created, which is after the `boost::bind` call has returned.

You should try to avoid needing a pointer to the thread object from within the thread itself.  Take a look at the functions in the [`boost::this_thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread) namespace instead.

Comment: `t` **is** initialized, it is just an empty shared_ptr at the time it is passed to `thread_routine`, since it has not been assigned yet. For instance passing `t` by reference (and keeping it alive) would work imo.

Comment: @sbabbi Yes it would work, but it would completely refute the purpose of the shared_ptr. Better to share the actual thread-reference then